# Unable to Check the Splash Screen displaying or not, after launching the app using calabash

Tags: automation, splash-screen, calabash, calabash-android, calabash-ios

utomating the Test case(splash screen is visible or not & how much time it is displaying) using calabash.
First I'm trying to verify whether the splash screen is displaying or not after launching the app. But i couldn't achieve. Please help me in doing only in calabash-ios or calabash-android